# Routes.rb: Multiple Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, aptana, aptana3

I have been able to view a single controller at localhost with port 3000 using root 'controller#action'. I would like to view multiple controllers using the routes.rb config file. Please advise if I am not following the best path. Should I create a different view/controller for each control such as textfield, dropdown, etc. I am new to ruby on rails and web development.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do with Rails controller actions what most would do with Javascript and Ajax. Generally, controller actions manipulate the database for the view, such as loading a variable, or variables.You pull those variables into your view then. If you're feeling lost, you might try this excellent tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Rails Routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) - this explains how to do it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, :posts, :transactions
```

This will create a series of `RESTful` routes which you can use in your application, for any controller

---

> Should I create a different view/controller for each control such as
>   textfield, dropdown

Each `controller/action` is basically what your users will see when they hit a specific "page" on your site. Each `view` shows the user a bunch of HTML; each `controller` creates the variables to use in that view; each `model` pulls relevant data from the database

You should read about [how to get started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to see how this works

Comment: TY Rich for the explanation.